# ListView Error in Android

Tags: android

I am New In android, i want to show a List view in a my Layout and code following But it throw Fatal error Please suggest me

Activity Code:

```
String [] frnds = {"Ajay Kumar", "Atul kumar", "Deepak Arora", "Mamta kri", "Mimi"};
ListView frndlist;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, frnds));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    frndlist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    frndlist.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,frnds));

}
```

Comment: You need to reveal us more: error details and `activity_main` xml layout

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed something, change your code to the following:

```
frndlist.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,frnds));
```